Find duplicates in a spreadsheet within a month
I have a spreadsheet in the following format:



ID
RESPONSIBLE
MONTH




10
JOHN
1


10
MARK
1


20
JOHN
2


30
JOHN
3


20
MARK
3


30
MARK
3



I need a way to get only the lines with duplicate Ids within the same months, giving me the following result:



ID
RESPONSIBLE
MONTH




10
JOHN
1


10
MARK
1


30
JOHN
3


30
MARK
3



Do anyone know how to achieve this result?
Thanks!
I tried multiple combinations of COUNT.IF and QUERY, but I never got a satisfying result

You can use the FILTER function as follows:
=FILTER(A2:C,1<COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,C2:C,C2:C))


